# EXC_BREAKPOINT using UITableViewCell's textLabel's text in a test target

Tags: ios, uitableview, tdd, ocunit, sentestingkit

I have a test target where I am testing a table view data source.I want to test that the cell's `textLabel` returned by `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` contains the text I expect, but when I set the textLabel's text I get a EXC_BREAKPOINT exception...

Does it have anything to do with the fact that not all classes in UIKit are possible to use in a test target(not sure if that's true anyway)?

Am I missing any special setting in the test target?

Would like to remark that my code is within a static library.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded the solution [here](http://paulsolt.com/2012/12/unit-testing-static-libraries-with-kiwi-for-ios-development/). Basically, you have to add an iPhone Application target with its own unit test target and doing all the UIKit-related testing there.